# Example of Frobenius Group

Tags: group-theory

Is ${\mathbb{Z}}_7 \rtimes {\mathbb{Z}}_3$ a Frobenius group? If it is a Frobenius group, then what is its kernel?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Btw, the answer is "yes".

Comment: To be pedantic (which I believe to be desirable), in order to define a semidirect product $K \rtimes H$, you need to specify a homomorphism $\phi: H \to {\rm Aut}(K)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A brute force approach:

We can take the group to be $\langle a,b|a^7=b^3=1,b^{-1}ab=a^2\rangle$. We take $K=\langle a\rangle,H=\langle b\rangle$.

Note that we have

\begin{align}
ba=a^4b & & b^2a=a^2b^2\\
ba^2=ab & & b^2a^2=a^4b^2\\
ba^3=a^5b & & b^2a^3=a^6b^2\\
ba^4=a^2b & & b^2a^4=ab^2\\
ba^5=a^3b & & b^2a^5=a^3b^2\\
ba^6=a^3b & & b^2a^6=a^5b^2
\end{align}

We find the conjugates of $H$.

\begin{align}a^{-1}ba=a^3b & & a^{-1}b^2a=ab^2 \\
a^{-2}ba^2=a^6b & & a^{-2}b^2a^2=a^2b^2 \\
a^{-3}ba^3=a^2b & & a^{-3}b^2a^3=a^3b^2\\ 
a^{-4}ba^4=a^5b & & a^{-4}b^2a^4=a^4b^2\\
a^{-5}ba^5=ab & & a^{-5}b^2a^5=a^5b^2\\
a^{-6}ba^6=a^4b & & a^{-6}b^2a^6=a^6b^2
\end{align}

So we certainly get all elements except possibly $a,a^2,\dots,a^6$. Can we get any of them? Consider $(a^ib)^{-1}b(a^ib)=b^2a^{-i}ba^ib$. That will evidently give $a^kb$ for some $k$, and so conjugating $b^2$ will give $a^kb^2$ for some $k$. Similarly, conjugating with $a^ib^2$ will fail to give an element $a^k$.

So the elements not in **any** conjugate of $H$ are just $K\setminus\{1\}$, which shows that $K$ is the Frobenius kernel and we have a Frobenius group.

Comment: Thank you for the solution